# Any benefit in putting buttons inside html form?

Tags: html

Is there any advantage in putting a button inside a html form vs using it directly in the body?

```
<form id="viewForm" method="post">
  <input id="editBtn" type="button" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @KenpachiZaraki, my question was a bit more deep. I know the basic differences, but they all can be achieved with javascript with ~no overhead. Given that, are there any reason to choose one way or the other?

Answer (score 0):

the main advantage of putting it into a form is that you can use

```
   <form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">
```

and the button will work with the action. like

for example a send button

```
  <form name="input" action="demo_form_action.asp" method="get">
      Username: <input type="text" name="user">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

a Button without a form can be used to call a function for example

```
  <button onlick="function();"></button>
```

but you can use the onclick eventhandler for links just the same
so a button only makes sense when using it with a form (most of the time)

you can use search for more examples for buttons and event handlers